# How to run function when series of readFile calls finish in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

In node.js, I have a module that loops through a folder of files. That actually has a function callback that triggers when it finishes reading from directory. However for each file it finds, I run a readFile command which is async function, to read the file, and that has a callback function too. The question is, how can I set it up so that there is a callback once the directory looping function finishes and also each of the readFile functions?

```
var klaw = require('klaw');
var fse = require('fs-extra');

var items = [];

klaw("items").on('data', function (item) {
    var dir = item.path.indexOf(".") == -1;
    // if its a file
    if (!dir) {
        var filename = item.path;
        if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".json")) {
            fse.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                items.push(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
            });
        }
    }
}).on('end', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
    import Promise from 'Bluebird';

    const processing = []
    const items = [];

   klaw("items")
    .on('data', item => processing.push(
      Promise.promisify(fs.readFile))(item.path)
      .then(content => items.push(JSON.parse(content.toString())))
      .catch(err => null)
    )
    .on('end', () => {
        Promise.all(processing)
        .then(nothing => console.log(items))
    })
```

or like

```
const processing = []

klaw("items")
.on(
  'data',
  item => processing.push(Promise.promisify(fs.readFile)(item.path))
)
.on(
  'end',
  () => {
    Promise.all(processing)
    .then(contents => (
      contents.map(content =>(JSON.parse(content.toString())))
    )
    .then(items => console.log(items))

})
```

Comment: Promise.promisify is undefined

Comment: you have to import bluebird

Comment: How can you modify the code, so it excludes folders? I had that check in my code above.

Comment: for your second example.